# passing object having other object using serializable .giving error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, serialization

i want to pass a custom model form fragment to another fragment. my Model is :

```
    public class AddressBookModel  implements Serializable {
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getReion() {
        return reion;
    }

    public void setReion(String reion) {
        this.reion = reion;
    }

    public String getLandlineNo() {
        return landlineNo;
    }

    public void setLandlineNo(String landlineNo) {
        this.landlineNo = landlineNo;
    }

    public String getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getPrifix() {
        return prifix;
    }

    public void setPrifix(String prifix) {
        this.prifix = prifix;
    }

    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String country;
    String street;
    String pincode;
    String city;
    String reion;
    String landlineNo;
    String mobileno;
    String prifix;


}
```

and another model class is

```
  public class OrderDataModel implements Serializable{

   public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public ArrayList<ProductBuyDataModel> getbuyProductDetail() {
        return buyProductDetail;
    }

    public void setbuyProductDetail(ArrayList<ProductBuyDataModel> productBuyDataModelsArraylist) {
        this.buyProductDetail = productBuyDataModelsArraylist;
    }

    String phoneno;

    public String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }



    String userId,emailAddress;
ArrayList<ProductBuyDataModel> buyProductDetail;

    public AddressBookModel getShipAddDetail() {
        return shipAddDetail;
    }

    public void setShipAddDetail(AddressBookModel shipAddDetail) {
        this.shipAddDetail = shipAddDetail;
    }

    public AddressBookModel getBillAddDetail() {
        return billAddDetail;
    }

    public void setBillAddDetail(AddressBookModel billAddDetail) {
        this.billAddDetail = billAddDetail;
    }

    AddressBookModel shipAddDetail,billAddDetail;
}
```

it successfully transfer the data to fragment but it after that it show a error

```
RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.laxmikantbolya.shreenamokar.Model.OrderDataModel)
```

i don't know why error  comes after sending data.i use OrderDataModel
for  passing data . it contains another model class as variable .
simple single model is easily i can send . but i have problem to pass a object
containing another object .

i don't no why  "Parcelable encountered IOException" comes even i dont use parcealble any where in my model list.

Logcat Output

```
09-07 06:16:56.620 18732-18732/com.example.laxmikantbolya.shreenamokar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.laxmikantbolya.shreenamokar, PID: 18732
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.laxmikantbolya.shreenamokar.Model.OrderDataModel)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1388)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
     at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:138)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:376)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2884)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3261)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.laxmikantbolya.shreenamokar.Model.ProductBuyDataModel
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:648)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1033)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1383)
     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
     at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:138) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191) 
     at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:376) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2884) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

programme is

```
 for (int i =0;i<buynowModelList.size();i++){
                        ProductBuyDataModel productBuyDataModel = new ProductBuyDataModel();
                        productBuyDataModel.setPrductId(String.valueOf(buynowModelList.get(i).getProductId()));
                        productBuyDataModel.setQuantity(String.valueOf(buynowModelList.get(i).getQuantity()));
                        productBuyDataModelArrayList.add(productBuyDataModel);
                    }
                 HashMap<String,String> hashMaploginDetail =sessionManager.getUserDetails();
                orderDataModel.setbuyProductDetail(productBuyDataModelArrayList);
                orderDataModel.setUserId(hashMaploginDetail.get(SessionManager.KEY_UserIdLOGin));
                orderDataModel.setEmailAddress(hashMaploginDetail.get(SessionManager.KEY_EmailLOGin));
                orderDataModel.setPhoneno(hashMaploginDetail.get(SessionManager.KEY_PhoneNO));




                bundle.putSerializable("buyNowData",orderDataModel);
                PlaceOrderAddFragment placeOrderAddFragment =new PlaceOrderAddFragment();
                placeOrderAddFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.buynow_frame,placeOrderAddFragment,TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

or getting it as

```
if (bundle.getSerializable("buyNowData")!=null){
            orderDataModel = (OrderDataModel) bundle.getSerializable("buyNowData");
        }
```

i recive the complet data . but after that it show me error and app crash.

i google as much as i can but i find only simple model to pass .they are not helpfull for me 
please send me any link that can help me .

Comment: put intent in which you pass this class

Comment: i have to pass form fragment to fragment  in same actvity .

Comment: put that code here

Comment: bundle.putSerializable("buyNowData",orderDataModel);
                       
 PlaceOrderAddFragment placeOrderAddFragment =new PlaceOrderAddFragment();
                        
placeOrderAddFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.buynow_frame,placeOrderAddFragment,TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: put your full code in your question

Comment: Try to remove the `implements Serializable` from your both models and then check. @laxmikant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing model object then all of your inner models should implement with Serializable. So, please check as i see another data model in your OrderDataModel class with name "ProductBuyDataModel". Make sure it is also implemented with Serialzeable.

Hope so, this might help!